# XOR-based key splitting with 3 parties and a threshold of 2

Tags: cryptography, xor

I have a task:

> Let’s say a bank has a cypher key K (just a long random string). That
>   bank wishes to split it into two pieces p1 and p2 so that both are
>   required for decryption. The p1 is then given to one executive, and p2
>   - to another, so both must contribute their pieces for decryption to proceed.
>
> To accomplish that, the bank generates random k1 and sets k′1←k⊕k1. Note
>   that k1⊕k′1=k. The bank gives k1 to one executive and k′1 to another.
>   Both must be present for decryption to proceed since, by itself, each
>   piece contains no information about the secret key k.
>
> Now, suppose the bank wants to split k into three pieces p1,p2,p3 so
>   that any two of the pieces enable decryption using k. This ensures
>   that even if one executive is out sick, decryption can still succeed,
>   but no employee can decrypt a message alone. To do so, the bank
>   generates two random pairs (k1,k′1) and (k2,k′2) as in the previous
>   paragraph so that k1⊕k′1=k2⊕k′2=k. How should the bank assign pieces
>   so that any two pieces enable decryption using k, but no single piece
>   can decrypt?
>
> What is the answer to the question above?
>
> ```
>  p1 = (k1, k2), p2 = (k`1, k2), p3 = (k`2);
>
>  p1 = (k1, k2), p2 = (k`1, k`2), p3 = (k`2);
>
>  p1 = (k1, k2), p2 = (k1, k2), p3 = (k`2);
>
>  p1 = (k1, k2), p2 = (k1), p3 = (k`2);
>
>  p1 = (k1, k2), p2 = (k2, k`2), p3 = (k`2);
> ```

Explain me please, how does it work.

Comment: Is this like a homework question, where you are constrained to use a logical XOR as described? Because that's not an accepted method of splitting a secret into shares.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is the answer:

```
p1 = (k1, k2), p2 = (k`1, k2), p3 = (k`2);
```

because each possible pair can generate `k`:

- p1 & p2: k1 ⊕ k'1 = k
- p1 & p3: k2 ⊕ k'2 = k
- p2 & p3: k2 ⊕ k'2 = k

Of course each of the parties cannot reconstruct the key by themselves.

The other possibilities are clearly wrong. Let's take the second possible answer and see if p2 & p3 can form a valid key. They cannot, because each have the same k'2 component, so that's not enough. Then p2 has a k'1, but p3 doesn't have a k1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved problem, see [Shamir's Secret Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing):

> Shamir's Secret Sharing is an algorithm in cryptography created by Adi Shamir. It is a form of secret sharing, where a secret is divided into parts, giving each participant its own unique part, where some of the parts or all of them are needed in order to reconstruct the secret.
>
> Counting on all participants to combine the secret might be impractical, and therefore sometimes the threshold scheme is used where any
> k of the parts are sufficient to reconstruct the original secret.

A possible *weak* 2 of 3 method might be possible using the same scheme that is used in three disk RAID5, any two can reconstitue the original.